# Utilizar un tipo de fuente tipografica desdé archivo

Tags: python

Como puedo utilizar una fuente no instalada en Windows desdé mí aplicación de Python. Tengo la fuente tipografica como recurso pero no instalada alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: Python puro no tiene soporte para cargar fuentes además de tkinter. Así que la respuesta depende de la librería que uses para cargarla. Podrías aclarar la librería por favor?